# Canvas doesn't draw line where it told so

Tags: javascript, canvas, 2d

I have this weird behavior by canvas, I am trying to draw path on canvas using mouse as in free drawing, the canvas draws line correctly on X coordinate but Y start correct then slip away as mouse is moving down, what am I doing wrong or missing?

```
<html>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
        var offset = function(obj) {
            var curleft = 0, curtop = 0;
            if (obj.offsetParent) {
                do {
                    curleft += obj.offsetLeft;
                    curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                return { x: curleft, y: curtop };
            }
            return undefined;
        }
        var canvas = document.getElementById("d");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        context.fillStyle = "#fff";
        context.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 300);
        var draw = false;
        var pos = offset(canvas);
        canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
            if (draw == false) { return; }
            var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
            var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
            console.log(x,y);
            context.lineTo(x, y);
            context.stroke();
        }
        canvas.onmousedown = function(e) {
            draw = true;
            var x = e.pageX - pos.x;
            var y = e.pageY - pos.y;
            context.fillStyle = "#000";
            context.beginPath();
            context.moveTo(x, y);
        }
        canvas.onmouseup = function(e) {
            draw = false;
        }
}
</script>
<style>
#d { border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; height: 300px; }
</style>
<canvas id="d"></canvas>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to add the width/height attributes to your canvas. 

I tried < canvas id="d" width='300' height='300'>  on a fiddle and it worked.

Comment: Can you please explain the why part? I have add with and height attributes and it worked, thank you very much but I do not understand how has happened.

Comment: Sorry I really don't know why, in my opinion it seems to be a browser implementation thing, because you're rectangle renders well but your paths no.<Br/>If you see here you see that the default height is 150 [w3c](  http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_canvas_height.asp), the more logic for me should be to take your css styles but it seems that for some reason it don't.

Comment: @marspzb: w3schools is not a proper source, it has a lot of errors in many places and I would suggest using Mozilla Developer Network instead, for example.

Comment: @Tadeck you're right MDN is a better source. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Basic_usage) there it says that when no width/height it's specified it takes 300x150 by default. And it recommends to put those attributes. thank you.